# problems to get correct reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created an extension for UITableView and want to get the correct reuseIdentifier at runtime, but I can't:

```
extension UITableView {

func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {

    let s = T.reuseIdentifier
```

The variable "s" always contains "UITableViewCell" and not the name which I did specify within the storyboard.

Comment: what's "reuseIdentifier" ? you declared some variable ?

Comment: @Amit it's a property on reusable cells, but it's not set until its dequeued.

Comment: I reverted the last edit because it made the answers pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, the whole method

```
extension UITableView {

    func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        return self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! T 
    }
}
```

is supposed to work correctly.

---

An alternative is a protocol extension and `static` methods, just adopt the protocol in the `UITableViewCell` subclasses.

```
protocol Reusable {
    associatedtype CellType : UITableViewCell = Self

    static var cellIdentifier : String { get }
    static func dequeueReusableCell(in tableView : UITableView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellType
}

extension Reusable where Self : UITableViewCell {

    static var cellIdentifier : String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static func dequeueReusableCell(in tableView : UITableView, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellType {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CellType
    }
}
```

And call it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyTableViewCell.dequeueReusableCell(in: tableView, for: indexPath)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of handling this is as follows.

**I create a protocol which declares a type as loadable from a nib:**

```
//  MARK: Nib Loadable
public protocol NibLoadable {
    /// The name of the .xib file in which this view is defined.
    static var nibName: String { get }
}
//  MARK: Nib Loadable Convenience
public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {
    static var nibName: String { return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last! }
}
```

**I create another type which declares a type as reusable and automatically conform table and collection view cells:**

```
//  MARK: Reusable View
/**
Indicates that a view can be reused provided it matches a provided identifier.
*/
public protocol ReusableView: class {
    /// The identifier for this type of reusable view.
    static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}
//  MARK: Reusable View Convenience
public extension ReusableView where Self: UIView {
    static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String { return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last! }
}
extension UICollectionViewCell: ReusableView { }
extension UITableViewCell: ReusableView { }
```

**I then create an easy means with which to register such a cell:**

```
//  MARK: Registration
public extension UICollectionView {
    func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) {
        register(T.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
    }
    func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: NibLoadable {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: bundle)
        register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
    }
}
public extension UITableView {
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_: T.Type) {
        register(T.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
    }
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: NibLoadable {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: bundle)
        register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

**Finally I have a convenient way of dequeuing these cells:**

```
//  MARK: Dequeuing
public extension UICollectionView {
    func dequeue<T: UICollectionViewCell>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.defaultReuseIdentifier)")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
public extension UITableView {
    func dequeue<T: UITableViewCell>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.defaultReuseIdentifier)")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

In use the app I make the reuse identifier for any cell its class name. I then conform the cell like so:

```
extension PersonalDetailTableViewCell: NibLoadable { }
```

The owner of the table view will register the cell within `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.register(PersonalDetailTableViewCell.self)
```

Within the `cellForRow` function I'll dequeue appropriately:

```
let cell: PersonalDetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeue(for: indexPath)
```

I have made this [available in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/Infinity-James/d4dca026287672a97c507f02d0fa21be).

Comment: Wow, you're seriously overcomplicating it. No need for protocols. I do the same in a 20-line extension. https://gist.github.com/OscarApeland/80d1b1dd9f7534ffa0dc8c7173989ef6

Comment: That `NibLoadable` protocol is completely unnecessary. You can just extend `UIView` and drop the protocol. The same with `ReusableView`. Seriously overcomplicated.